# Json only web application. What are the cons? (or Pros)

Tags: javascript, json, architecture

I want to design a web application whose only interface is json i.e. all the http requests receive responses only in json format and dont render any html on the server side. All the form posts convert the form data into a json object and then post it as a string.  All the rendering is done by client side javascript.

The one downside of this approach I know is that browsers without javascript wont be able to do much with this architecture but the interaction on the site is rich enough to be useless to non-javascript browsers anyway.

Are there any other downsides of this approach of designing a web application?

Comment: Can anyone share any ideas about SEO for such architecture?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an increasingly-common pattern, with tools such as GWT and ext-js. Complex web apps such as GMail have been over 90% JS-created DOM for some time. If you are developing a traditional 'journal' type website with mainly written content to be read this approach will be overkill. But for a complex app that wishes to avoid page refreshes it may well be appropriate.

One downside is that not only does it require a browser that supports JavaScript, it is also easy for the computing resources required by the app to creep up to the point where it needs quite a powerful browser. If you develop in Chrome on a top-end PC you might come to run the app on a less powerful machine such as a netbook or mobile device and find it has become quite sluggish.

Another downside is you lose the opportunity to use HTML tools when working on your pages, and that viewing your application's pages' DOM trees under Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools may be hard work because the relationship between the elements and your code may not be clear.

Edit: another thing to consider is that it is more work to make pages more accessible, as keyboard shortcuts may have to be added (you may not be able to use the browser built in behavior here) and users with special needs may find it more difficult to vary the appearance of the app, for instance by increasing font size.

Another edit: it's unlikely now text content on your website will be successfully crawled by search engines. For this reason you sometimes see server created text-only pages representing the same content, that refer browsers to the JS-enabled version of the page.

Comment: Good point about client-side resource consumption. Apps like these are what makes Firefox grow 2 GB large when you check your E-Mail (I'm exaggerating, but it's not far from the truth). However, if you can rely on the user's machine to be either strong or use a decent browser, it is no big deal.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools is a sample of such application.

Comment: i think the last 3 points aren't really a worry if you know what you are doing

Answer (score 5):

Other than the issue you point out, there's another: Speed. But it's not necessarily a big issue, and in fact using JSON rather than HTML may (over slower connections) improve rather than hamper speed.

Web browsers are highly optimised to render HTML, both whole pages (e.g., normally) and fragments (e.g., `innerHTML` and the various wrappers for it, like jQuery's `html` or Prototype's `update`). There's a lot you can do to minimize the speed impact of working through your returned data and rendering the result, but nothing is going to be *quite* as fast as grabbing some HTML markup from the server and dumping it into the browser for display.

Now, that said, it's not necessarily going to be a *big* problem at all. If you use efficient techniques (some notes [in this article](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/)), and if you primarily render the results by building up HTML strings you're then going to hand to the brower (again, via `innerHTML` or wrappers for it), or if you're rending only a few elements at a time, it's unlikely that there will be any perceptible speed difference.

If, instead, you build up substantial trees by creating and appending individual elements via the DOM API or wrappers for it, you're very likely to notice a performance impact. That *seems* like the right thing to do, but it involves lots of trips across the DOM/JavaScript boundary and means the browser has to present the DOM version of things to your code at all intermediate steps; in contrast, when you hand it an HTML string, it can do its thing and romp through it full-speed-ahead. You can see the difference in [this performance test](http://jsperf.com/build-table-via-markup-vs-dom). It's substantial.

Over slower connections, the speed impact may be made up for or even overcome if the JSON data is more compact than the HTML would have been, because of the smaller size on the wire.

Answer (score 5):

You've got to be more mindful of high-latency, low-bandwidth connections when you're building something like this. The likelihood is, you're going to be making a lot of Ajax calls to sync data and grab new data from the server, and the lag can be noticeable if there's a lot of latency. You need a strategy in place to keep the user informed about the progress of any communication between client and server.

In development, it's something that can be overlooked, especially if you're working with a local web server, but it can be killer in production. It means looking into prefetching and caching strategies.

You also need an effective way to manage HTML fragments/templates. Obviously, there are some good modules out there for rendering templates - Mustache.js, Underscore template, etc. - but keeping on top of the HTML fragments can cause some maintenance headaches. I tend to store the HTML templates in separate files, and load them dynamically via Ajax calls (plus caching to minimise HTTP requests).

Edit - another con:

Data syncing - if you use a server database as your data "authority" then it's important to keep data in sync between the server and client. This is even more relevant if changes to data on one client affects multiple clients. You then get into the realms of dealing with realtime, asynchronous updates, which can cause some interesting conceptual challenges. (Fortunately, using frameworks and libraries such as Socket.IO and Backbone.js can really make things easier).

Edit - pros:

There are some huge advantages to this type of application - it's far more responsive, and can really enhance the user experience. Trivial actions that would normally require a round-trip to the server and incur network overhead can now be performed quickly and seamlessly.

Also, it allows you to more effectively couple data to your views. Chances are, if you're handling the data on the client-side, you will have a framework in place that allows you to organise the data and make use of an ORM - whether its Backbone.js, Knockout.js or something similar. You no longer have to worry about storing data in html attributes or in temporary variables. Everything becomes a lot more manageable, and it opens the door for some really sophisticated UI development.

Also also, JavaScript opens up the possibility for event-driven interaction, which is the perfect paradigm for highly interactive applications. By making use of the event loop, you can hook your data directly to user-initiated and custom events, which opens up great possibilities. By hooking your data models directly to user-driven events, you can robustly handle updates and changes to data and render the appropriate output with minimal fuss. And it all happens at high speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing is what is your requirement, if you want to build a interactive application, giving desktop like feel then go for client side development. Using Javascript framework like backbone.js or knockout.js will really help in organizing and maintaining the code. The advantages are already detailed out in previous answers. As respect to the performance in rendering with respect to server side rendering is concerned here is a nice blog post which made thinking.
http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/